# Why does executing "mvn clean package" to build Spark fail with "Some Enforcer rules have failed"?

Tags: maven, apache-spark

I'm getting build error when trying to build a clean version of latest Spark. I did the following

**1)** git clone https://github.com/apache/spark.git

**2)** build `mvn -DskipTests clean package`

But I get the following error:

> Spark Project Parent POM .......................... FAILURE [2.338s]
>
> ...
>
> BUILD FAILURE ...
>
> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-enforcer-plugin:1.4:enforce
>   (enforce-versions) on project spark-parent_2.10: Some Enforcer rules
>   have failed. Look above for specific messages explaining why the rule
>   failed. -> [Help 1]
>
> [ERROR]
>
> [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with
>   the -e switch.
>
> [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
>
> [ERROR]
>
> [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions,
>   please read the following articles:
>
> [ERROR] [Help 1]
>   http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException

I'm running Lubuntu 14.04 with the following:

java version "1.7.0_91"

OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.6.3) (7u91-2.6.3-0ubuntu0.14.04.1)

OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.91-b01, mixed mode)

Apache Maven 3.0.5

Comment: Updating Maven version to 3.3.9 solved the issue

Comment: Can you make it the answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Updating Maven version to 3.3.9 solved the issue